# Android tabwidget

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am using tabwidget when i apply white theme on tab widget selected tab text remain black but unselected tab text turn into white and invisible, how can i change the color of tab widget indicator text.
[alt text http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/3238/tabt.jpg](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/3238/tabt.jpg)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906314/android-tabwidget-in-light-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the issue using the following code

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```